How can I exit on one bar and wait to enter until the next bar?
@vitruvius, thank you for advising on to use last_exit_bar_idx!
I tried to apply it but the script below keeps skipping bars before entering a new trade. Kindly advise on what could be wrong.
// Variables to track trade logic
var int last_exit_bar_idx = na
var bool enter_next_long = false
var bool enter_next_short = false

// Exit logic and prepare for next-bar entry
if inDateRange
    if strategy.position_size > 0 // Currently in a long position
        if bearish
            strategy.close("long", comment="exit long")
            last_exit_bar_idx := bar_index
            enter_next_short := true
            enter_next_long := false

    if strategy.position_size < 0 // Currently in a short position
        if bullish
            strategy.close("short", comment="exit short")
            last_exit_bar_idx := bar_index
            enter_next_long := true
            enter_next_short := false

// Enter positions on the next bar after exit
if inDateRange and strategy.position_size == 0
    if enter_next_short and bar_index == last_exit_bar_idx + 1
        strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="enter short")
        enter_next_short := false
        last_exit_bar_idx := na

    if enter_next_long and bar_index == last_exit_bar_idx + 1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="enter long")
        enter_next_long := false
        last_exit_bar_idx := na

// Handle initial trades when no exits exist
if inDateRange and na(last_exit_bar_idx) and strategy.position_size == 0
    if bullish
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="first long")
        last_exit_bar_idx := bar_index
    if bearish
        strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="first short")
        last_exit_bar_idx := bar_index


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use
last_exit_bar_idx = strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
To get the bar index of when the last trade was closed. Then just use it as an entry condition ((bar_index - last_exit_bar_idx) > n) where n is how many bars you want to wait.

Thank you so much!  That seems promising.  I tried to implement it as per below but trades are not entered on the next bar. It looks fine I think but something must be wrong. Please advise.
